# Error when trying to install Nebular into my Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nebular

I'm really new to angular and I'm trying to install Nebular using: `ng add @nebular/theme`. Unfortunately, I get an error.

After inputing the command into my terminal, I get this error:

```
? Which Nebular theme do you want to use: cosmic
? Use customizable scss themes? Yes
? Set up browser animations for Nebular? Yes
UPDATE package.json (1426 bytes)
✔ Packages installed successfully.
UPDATE package.json (1426 bytes)
✔ Packages installed successfully.
Could not read Angular module file: /src/null.ts
```

I'm confused why I'm getting an error! I created the app with `ng new myapp` and everything went smoothly with that. Already tried sudo, and creating a new app just in case but same error.